# Export each spreadsheet to a separate workbook (Something except VBA)

Tags: python, excel, vba, python-3.x

I have huge Excel workbook with plenty of sheets.

This is simple solution by using VBA to export each sheet to a different file (workbook).

Main issue, it is slow.

```vb
Sub Splitbook()
    MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        sht.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
            Filename:=MyPath & "\XXX" & sht.Name & ".xlsx"

        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Looking for any idea related to VBS, Python... Because based on internet research, I could not find anything related.

Comment: VBA is the quickest. Your code is slow and doing what you are doing in any other language will be even slower.

Comment: I assume that you have to do this on regular basis (as in create new files for each sheet). If so, have you considered creating the files once for each sheet and then just reference the sheets in these files?

Comment: @AMagpie Any suggestion about code optimisation?

Comment: @Zac this is how they want.... not making decisions... currently trying to find quicker way to do it.

Comment: Well you could turn of lots of things first like Application.ScreenUpdating, Calculation mode etc. SO is not really for code optimization - though you will find lots of information here for optimization. Optimization problems may be candidates for Code Review site.

Comment: @QHarr sorry miss understanding, I thought you about the way the actual VBA works.

Comment: TBH the line becomes blurred.  If you search stack overflow for vba optimization or even google you will get lots of info on optimizing but with so little code it could be, not 100% sure, that you sre looking at what you can switch off whilst performing your operations and using With statements etc. http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm

Comment: @QHarr I did all of this, how I understood, nothing quicker can be used .... eh..

Comment: I'd say setting `ScreenUpdating` to `False` alone should improve performance significantly.

Comment: Your code posted doesn't show that you had tried this. In an optimization problem would be a very good idea to show your optimization efforts ;-)

Comment: You can see my VBA specific answer here on optimising VBA. And a link to optimising Excel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071366/how-to-speed-up-multiple-replacement-using-vba-in-word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here are a few observations though:

1. You can switch off [things](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm) that aren't required which consume resources e.g. `Application.ScreenUpdating` . I have borrowed a sub by [@Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467663/make-the-vba-code-go-faster) that switches off the common items.
2. Use With statement
3. Work with only the UsedRange not the whole sheet
4. You might ignore this as I have ignored the Format part of your paste but have simply converted to values by setting the .Value = .Value for the conversion

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public Sub Splitbook()

       Dim MyPath As String
       Dim sht As Worksheet

       appTGGL bTGGL:=False

       MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

       For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

           sht.Copy

           With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
               .Value = .Value
           End With

           ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
           Filename:=MyPath & "\XXX" & sht.Name & ".xlsx"

           ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

       Next sht

       appTGGL bTGGL:=True

   End Sub


   Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True) 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467663/make-the-vba-code-go-faster

       With Application
           .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
           .EnableEvents = bTGGL
           .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
           .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
           .CutCopyMode = False
           .StatusBar = vbNullString
       End With

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Should you turn appTGGL back on at the end?

Comment: @ajd absolutely should. Thanks.